# How to make this colorful shiny bubble in blender2.8? (iridescence)

Tags: materials

[image]

I want make something like this but have no idea

Comment: Hello, what have you tried? Is this to be in Eevee or Cycles? What have you done so far? [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/191752/edit) your question and add  you current results (node setup and render) please so that others can see what you are currently having problems with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a shader like this. I find it works best with the Blend Mode set to "Alpha Hashed" (highlighted). I also found equally pleasing, but different results by using different inputs for the ColorRamp Leading to the Emission. The ones I found to work best are Position, Normal, Tangent, True Normal, and Reflection (also highlighted). Make sure bloom is enabled for the full effect. Make sure to rotate around the sphere as well, as the colors change based on position.

If you're wondering, the Noise Texture I used as a displacement is just to give it a bit of a "warped bubble" look to make it look more natural and to show off the colors better.

[image: GlowOrb]

Comment: Thanks that help me a lot